# list to dict with a group by on first value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures

Is there any trick in order to easily transform a list to a dict with this specific format? I have been unable to do so.

FROM :

```
a = [
    ('A', 'B', 8),
    ('A', 'D', 10),
    ('A', 'E', 12),
    ('B', 'C', 6),
    ('B', 'F', 12),
    ('C', 'F', 8),
    ('D', 'E', 10),
    ('D', 'G', 30),
    ('E', 'F', 10),
    ('F', 'G', 12)
]
```

TO :

```
b = {
    "A": {"B": 8, "D": 10, "E": 12},
    "B": {"C": 6, "F": 12},
    "C": {"F": 8},
    "D": {"E": 10, "G": 30},
    "E": {"F": 10},
    "F": {"G": 12}
}
```

Thanks in advance you your tips

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Seems pretty straightforward. Loop over the list, create the dict at that key as needed, update the dict...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loop the list, check if the key is in the dict. if it is then add to the dict of that key. if its not then create the keys dict:

```
a = [
    ('A', 'B', 8),
    ('A', 'D', 10),
    ('A', 'E', 12),
    ('B', 'C', 6),
    ('B', 'F', 12),
    ('C', 'F', 8),
    ('D', 'E', 10),
    ('D', 'G', 30),
    ('E', 'F', 10),
    ('F', 'G', 12)
]

final_list = {}
for item in a:
    if item[0] in final_list.keys():
        final_list[item[0]][item[1]] = item[2]
    else:
        final_list[item[0]] = {item[1]: item[2]}
print(final_list)
```

Comment: You could replace `for item in a:` with `for key1,key2,value in a:`. Then the complicated `final_list[item[0]][item[1]] = item[2]` becomes a simple `final_list[key1][key2] = value`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `defaultdict` from collections module:

```
from collections import defaultdict

b = defaultdict(dict)
for k, k1, v in a:
    b[k].update({k1: v})
```

Output:

```
>>> b
defaultdict(dict,
            {'A': {'B': 8, 'D': 10, 'E': 12},
             'B': {'C': 6, 'F': 12},
             'C': {'F': 8},
             'D': {'E': 10, 'G': 30},
             'E': {'F': 10},
             'F': {'G': 12}})
```

An alternative version without `defaultdict`:

```
b = {}
for k, k1, v in a:
    t = b.setdefault(k, {})
    t[k1] = v
```

Comment: This is interesting. We need defaultdict because there needs to be a blank dict to update in the first place?

Comment: @RichardKYu. Yes exactly. It's avoid a conditional statement to check if the entry already exists or not.

Comment: @RichardKYu. In fact, you can easily replace `defaultdict` by the `setdefault` method of dict. `t` is the nested dict of each entry `k` like `{'A': {}}` *<- the nested dict is `t`*

Comment: Instead of `b[k].update({k1: v})`, I suggest `b[k][k1] = v`.

Comment: In the setdefault version, you could also write directly `b.setdefault(k, {})[k1] = v` instead of the two lines `t = b.setdefault(k, {}); t[k1] = v`, although that's mostly a matter of preference. (Personally, I think the two-lines version would be preferable *if* the variable name was helping understand the code; since `t` here doesn't mean anything, I prefer the one-line version.)

Comment: @Stef. I used `t` for temporary to better understand the mechanism and illustrate my comment above :) but you're totally right. I prefer also the one line version :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a beginner-friendly code.

1. We unpack the tuple and put the values in individual variables
2. If the key is already in `dic`, it means that a dictionary already exists and we simply add another pair.
3. Else, we make a new key value pair inside `dic` wherein the value is a dictionary.

```
list = [
    ('A', 'B', 8),
    ('A', 'D', 10),
    ('A', 'E', 12),
    ('B', 'C', 6),
    ('B', 'F', 12),
    ('C', 'F', 8),
    ('D', 'E', 10),
    ('D', 'G', 30),
    ('E', 'F', 10),
    ('F', 'G', 12)
]

dic = {}

for tuple in list:
    key, element, num = tuple
    if key in dic:
        dic[key][element] = num
    else:
        dic[key] = {element: num}

for k, v in dic.items():
    print(f"{k}: {v}")
```

Output:

```
{
    "A": {"B": 8, "D": 10, "E": 12},
    "B": {"C": 6, "F": 12},
    "C": {"F": 8},
    "D": {"E": 10, "G": 30},
    "E": {"F": 10},
    "F": {"G": 12}
}
```

Comment: This would be great, except you are recommending to use `tuple` and `list` as variable names. But `tuple` and `list` are already the names of builtin classes, and shadowing the name of a builtin is a really terrible habit.

Answer (score 1):

If the first level keys are in grouped order, you can use groupby from itertools in a dictionary comprehension:

```
from itertools import groupby

d = { k:{c:n for _,c,n in v} for k,v in groupby(a,key=lambda t:t[0]) }

print(d)

{'A': {'B': 8, 'D': 10, 'E': 12}, 
 'B': {'C': 6, 'F': 12}, 
 'C': {'F': 8}, 
 'D': {'E': 10, 'G': 30}, 
 'E': {'F': 10}, 
 'F': {'G': 12}}
```

Comment: Take care it works ONLY because the list is already sorted by the first key. Try `import random; random.shuffle(a)`. You have to use `groupby(sorted(a, key=lambda t: t[0]), key=lambda t: t[0])`